# Simple column and row ReOrdering with bootstrap mobile layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and its grid feature for my web layout. I have my base set up for medium and large screens, but I am developing my layout for small screens. I have been able to create the correct result, but it always makes the code much more complex. I wonder if there is a way, possibly using the bootstrap column ordering feature, of creating the layout below, without too much complication to the HTML, ideally just using HTML and CSS? Here is my code:

```
 <div class="container-fluid PageView text-center">
            <div class="row Page2">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></span> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"> </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"><h2>Title</h2></div>
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"><h2>Title</h2></div>
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"><h2>Title</h2></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"><p class="lead">Text</p></div>
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"><p class="lead">Text</p></div>
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"><p class="lead">Text</p></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My original layout ( which I want to keep for medium+ sized layouts ):

[1A]   [1B]   [1C]

[2A]   [2B]   [2C]

[3A]   [3B]   [3C]

This is the layout I would like for small screens.

[1A]

[1B]

[1C]

[2A] [3A]

[2B] [3B]

[2C] [3C]

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acheive this by nesting the **title** and **text** columns into new rows so when the viewport changes only the first 3 columns stack [1A, 1B, 1C] while the remaining (nested columns) fall into a 6x6 column formation.

See [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) and working example Snippet.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="alert alert-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></span> 1A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="alert alert-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> 1B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="alert alert-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> 1C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-info">
            <h2>Title 2A</h2>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <p class="lead">Text 3A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-info">
            <h2>Title 2B</h2>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <p class="lead">Text 3B</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-info">
            <h2>Title 2C</h2>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <p class="lead">Text 3C</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I modify this, to include blank columns to act as boarders? I would like the boxes to be 2 grid blocks wide, with 2 blank grid blocks on either side and 2 1-block margins in-between the boxes. I can make this work with the glyph boxes, but struggling with the title and test elements. How do I do this?

Comment: You'd need to post some kind of example and most likely a new question.